# Stored Procedure using Execute Immediate with binding

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, execute-immediate

I have a working Stored Procedure and would like to improve/simplify it.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DOCSADM.DRILL_COUNTV5 ( IN_TABLE IN VARCHAR2, IN_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, OUT_COUNT OUT NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || IN_TABLE 
          || ' WHERE TYPEVALUE = ''' || IN_TYPE || ''' ' 
          into OUT_COUNT;
END DRILL_COUNTV5;
/
```

I would ideally like to make it easier to expand. I would like to rewrite the execute immediate line like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || IN_TABLE 
     || ' WHERE TYPEVALUE = '':IN_TYPE'' ' 
     into OUT_COUNT;
```

When I use this method, I get 0 as my return value.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM :IN_TABLE WHERE TYPEVALUE = ''' || IN_TYPE 
     || ''' ' into OUT_COUNT;
```

This one gives me "ORA-00903: invalid table name".

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || IN_TABLE 
  || ' WHERE TYPEVALUE = '':1'' ' 
  into OUT_COUNT using IN_TYPE;
```

Gives me "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist".

I don't mind so much if the table binding doesn't happen because there will be fewer of those, but I really want to be able to do the where binding and not use the concatenation.

The [document from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm) gave me several methods, but when I tried them they just did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using USING clause in your procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE ttt(
  typevalue varchar2(10)
);

INSERT INTO ttt VALUES('123');

DECLARE 
  IN_TABLE varchar2(10) := 'ttt';
  typval varchar2(10) := '123';
  OUT_COUNT number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || IN_TABLE || ' WHERE TYPEVALUE = :p ' 
         INTO  OUT_COUNT USING IN typval;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( OUT_COUNT );
END;
/

==============================
dbms_output:
1
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1fb7e29017e3c5f4309ed25bbeddf7f6

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried that method, but it might have been before I got the execute immediate working by removing the into from being inside. When I tried this method it did work. Thank you